# Going on a cruise in 7 1/2 weeks, but my passport is expired, and I don't have a birth certificate with a seal. What are my options?

Tags: passports, canada, us-citizens, paperwork, cruising

I'm a natural-born US citizen.  I got a passport back in March 2000 for a trip to Germany.  Of course, that was more than 10 years ago, so the passport is expired, and being more than 15 years ago (15 years and 4 months now), is not eligible to be renewed.  I need to apply for a passport as a first-time applicant.

The trouble is that I'm leaving for a cruise that will be making stops in Canada in 7 1/2 weeks (September 5th, to be exact).  This WOULD be enough time to get a new passport, but the birth certificate I got from my parents doesn't have a official seal on it, and from what I've read [about the rules on birth certificates](http://www.travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/first-time.html), the certificate I have will likely not be accepted by the office when I attempt to get a new passport.  It came from a US Navy base hospital, and the entire thing is a photocopy except for a signature from the someone who's rank appears to be "PN1", whatever that means.  Nowhere on it are any embossed/raised seals.

According to [the California Department of Public Health website](http://www.cdph.ca.gov/certlic/birthdeathmar/Pages/ProcessingTimes.aspx), it will take about four weeks to receive a certified birth certificate, which wouldn't give me enough time to use it to get my passport.

From what I've read, I could use that birth certificate and my USA driver's license to get into Canada, but that getting back into the USA absolutely requires a passport.

What options do I have?  Am I screwed?

Comment: http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/canada.html  "For entry into the United States via land and sea borders, U.S. citizens must present either a U.S. passport, passport card, NEXUS card, Enhanced Drivers License, or other Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative (WHTI)-compliant document. The only exception to this requirement is for U.S. citizens under the age of 16 (or under 19, if traveling with a school, religious, or other youth group) who need only present a birth certificate, Consular Report of Birth Abroad, or naturalization certificate."

Comment: So there are other options, but the birth certificate isn't one of them.

Comment: The state website says that county records may be faster--is that a possibility? County recorder sites can often give you one immediately if you go in person.

Comment: That's not really an option for me since I live in Portland, OR and was born in San Diego, CA.

Comment: Can you get an enhanced driver's license in time ?

Comment: @Blackbird57 Oregon does not issue enhanced driver's licenses.

Comment: @Sohcahtoa82: A US citizen, who can satisfactorily prove his US citizenship (e.g. with birth certificate and photo ID, or expired US passport, etc), cannot ultimately be denied entry to the United States under any circumstances. So "getting back into the USA" does not "absolutely require" any particular thing.

Comment: You do get a free 30 minute lecture from CBP about the importance of having the proper documentation on you, though.

Answer (score 6):

If the cruise is a closed-loop cruise (i.e., it departs and returns to the same port in the US), then [you don't necessarily need a passport:](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1139/%7E/documents-needed-to-take-a-cruise)

> U.S. Citizens on closed-loop cruises will be able to enter or depart the country on the cruise with proof of citizenship, such as an original or copy of his or her birth certificate (issued by the Vital Records Department in the state where he or she was born) and, if 16 or older, a government issued photo ID.  ...  The United States does not require you to have a passport. (A Consular report of Birth Abroad issued by the Department of State or a Certificate of Naturalization is also acceptable.)
>
> HOWEVER, it is possible that one or more of the Caribbean Islands on your itinerary, does require you to have a passport to enter their country. In that case, it is very possible that the cruise line will require you to have a passport to board, even if it is not a U.S. requirement.

Note also that [Canada will accept a birth certificate](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/ivc-rnc-eng.html) as proof of citizenship for entry:

> If you are a U.S. citizen or permanent resident, you must carry proof of citizenship such as a passport, birth certificate, a certificate of citizenship or naturalization, a U.S. Permanent Resident Card, or a Certificate of Indian Status along with photo identification. If you are a U.S. permanent resident, ensure you carry proof of your status such as a U.S. Permanent Resident Card.

I would check all of this with the cruise line ahead of time to confirm that you'll be OK to board the boat without a passport.  I'm sure that this situation is not infrequent among cruise passengers.